# How to pass session confirmation number in REST API?

Tags: web-services, rest, atg

http://username:password@siteaddress.com/rest/model/atg/userprofiling/ProfileActor/create?_dynSessConf=1161953573111590000&email=t3June0@yopmail.com&password=project@3June0&confirmPassword=project@3June0

Even after passing session Confirmation number,I am getting the following error

Your Session expired due to inactivity.

This problem doesn't arise when i use Curl command.

Answer (score 0):

Is this Problem got Solved?, Is your Login API is working ? where are you using this ATG API (for mobile or web- portal ) ?

Answer is for Web portal.

> This error is because of sessionconfirmation number mismatch.

use this Code to retrieve session confirmation number.

```
var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlHttp.open( "GET", "http://IP:Port/rest/model/atg/rest/SessionConfirmationActor/getSessionConfirmationNumber", false ); // false for synchronous request
        xmlHttp.send(); 
        var hostResponse=xmlHttp.responseText.split(" ");
        localStorage.setItem("getSessionConfirmationNumer",hostResponse[1].replace("}", ""));
```

Session confirmation number is large,Number will assign to LONG if you are using json to retrieve the same.

Please check and let know. Good Luck :)